# Difference between => and : in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Wonder what's the difference between => and : in method header in Typescript? Thanks

```
  methodA: (
    fieldA: string,
  ) => interfaceA;

  methodA(
    fieldA: string
  ): interfaceA;
```

Comment: 1 used in interface declaration, second used in function declaration

Comment: Not much difference, but the latter allows you to define overloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big difference. Methods are bivariant. It means, that it is not safe to use them. Consider this example

```js
interface Bivariant {
    methodA(fieldA: string | number): void;
}


const bivariant: Bivariant = {
    methodA(fieldA: string) { // string is assignable to `fieldA` argument, not safe because it might be a number
        fieldA.includes('a')
    }
}

const foo = (arg: Bivariant) => {
    arg.methodA(42) // ok
}

foo(bivariant) // runtime error, no TS error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w8LXAw)

Please run this code. You will get a runtime error, because `methodA` in `bivariant` const expects a `string` argument and TS does not complain whereas according to `Bivariant` interface it might be also a `number`. Function `foo`, in turn, allows you to call `arg.methodA` with `number`.

Now, try to rewrite `Bivariance` interface with arrow function:

```js
interface Bivariant {
    methodA:(fieldA: string | number) => void;
}
```

**You will get an error.**

This behavior is by design. Please see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html) and [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance).

Apart from that, check:

- [this article](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) of `Stephan Boyer`,
- [this video](https://youtu.be/RH49aarW6sU?t=2332) of Titian-Cernicova-Dragomir 's talk and
- my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covariance-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc) where I listed all links about *-variance because this topic is very interesting.
- [here](https://catchts.com/mutations) you can find my article with some examples of TS mutations